# How can I the number of times the char occurs in the String,

Tags: java, string, char

I am doing a Junite test actually here is my solution

```
  public int count_one_char(String s, char c){
     int count = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)== c){
             count = count + 1;
         }

     }
 return count;

 }
```

and here is my test

```
    @Test public void tests2(){
    code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
    String input = "heyh ";
    int expected = 4;
    int actual = s.count_one_char(input);
    assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);
}
```

my eclipse shows The method count_one_char(String, char) in the type Solution is not applicable for the arguments (String)

so im stuck at here dont know how to pass char to the count_one_char method.

Comment: `java`/ `c`/ `c++`   /... chose any one please [looks like `java` only]

Comment: tag only the relevant language plz.

Answer (score 0):

The call `s.count_one_char(input);` is missing the second argument, so it doesn't match the signature of `count_one_char(String s, char c)`.

It should be something like:

```
s.count_one_char(input,'h');
```

Comment: so how can i declare a someChar local variable?

Comment: @QifengSun How about `char someChar = 'h';` (or whatever char you want to use).

Comment: But how can I count every char on the string?